# Vue.js: use CSS class for child element

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component `v-popup.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and I want to style it from the parent, for example:

```
<template>
  <v-popup class="custom-popup">
    Popup content
  </v-popup>
</template>

<style>
  .custom-popup {
    padding: 20px;
  }
</style>
```

How can I configure `v-popup.vue` component to make `custom-popup` class to be automatically added to `div.popup`, not `div.overlay` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Scoped Styles

- Using [scoped](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html) styles (in both parent and child) is a good idea and will make this solution easier.
- Instead of creating a new `custom-popup` class, use a [deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) in the parent. This allows the parent to define extra styles for child components that use the same selector.
- The deep selector looks like this: `>>>` unless you're using a SCSS/SASS pre-processor.  Then you use `::v-deep` instead.

```html
<template>
  <v-popup>
    Popup content
  </v-popup>
</template>

<style scoped>
  >>> .popup {
    padding: 20px;
  }

  /* If using SCSS/SASS, do this instead */
  /*
  ::v-deep .popup {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  */
</style>
```

The child will use *both* its own `.popup` class and the one from the parent.

If you didn't use scoped styles, it would quickly become a problem if you wanted to import the child in multiple parents and use different styles each time.

Answer (score 3):

In your v-popup.vue, you can do the following:

```
<template>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div :class="['popup', popupClass]">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 
export default {

// Do the usual implementations here...
props: {
 popupClass: ''
}

}

</script>
```

Then in your parent component, you can do the following:

```
<template>
  <v-popup popup-class="custom-popup">
    Popup content
  </v-popup>
</template>
```

However, I am curious. Why not encapsulate this class inside v-popup.vue. I seldom use this design unless there will be another component sharing this class from the parent.

EDIT (per your last comment):
You can use this link as a reference on how to use the $attr attribute: https://jsfiddle.net/changjoo_park/pzx08wp9/

So, in a sense, you can do the following, in your parent component

```
<template>
  <v-popup popup-class="custom-popup" v-bind="$attrs">
    Popup content
  </v-popup>
</template>
```

In your v-popup component:

```
<template>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div :class="['popup', $attrs.popupClass]">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 
export default {

// Do the usual implementations here...

}

</script>
```

So, no props implementations and the class is taken directly from the $attrs object. Hope this helps! You can read more about this usage here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-attrs

Comment: I'd like to prevent custom `popupClass` property. I'm wondering about using `$attrs`.

I agree with encapsulation, but project I'm working on has some legacy code around that, and I don't have time to refactoring it :(